# Has anyone encountered anything like this

Tags: security, androguard

```
WARNING:androguard.core.api_specific_resources:Requested API level 29 is larger than maximum we have, returning API level 28 instead.
[INFO] 26/Oct/2021 09:54:16 - Running APKiD 2.1.2
[ERROR] 26/Oct/2021 09:54:16 - Error Performing Static Analysis
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ACER\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\mobsf\StaticAnalyzer\views\android\static_analyzer.py", line 211, in static_analyzer
    apkid_results = apkid_analysis(app_dic[
  File "C:\Users\ACER\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\mobsf\MalwareAnalyzer\views\apkid.py", line 41, in apkid_analysis
    rules = options.rules_manager.load()
  File "C:\Users\ACER\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\apkid\rules.py", line 46, in load
    self.rules = yara.load(self.rules_path)
yara.Error: could not open file "C:\Users\ACER\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\Lib\site-packages\apkid\rules\rules.yarc"
[ERROR] 26/Oct/2021 09:54:16 - could not open file "C:\Users\ACER\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\Lib\site-packages\apkid\rules\rules.yarc"
[ERROR] 26/Oct/2021 09:54:16 - Internal Server Error: /static_analyzer/
ERROR:django.request:Internal Server Error: /static_analyzer/
```

**I would be glad to receive any information!!!**

Comment: related https://github.com/androguard/androguard/issues/735

Comment: Please edit the question title to be error specific.